# I receive this "error: 'string' not declared" when compiling

Tags: c++

I am running into an error when compiling.  The error states that 'string' is not declared.  I know I'm not supposed to "include" anything in these files.  The header file declares a class, and lists the member functions.  Two of those functions have an integer passed as a parameter, and two others have a string passed as a parameter.  The .cpp file is using namespace, and the string variable is definitely declared.  What could be the issue?

Security.h

```
class Security
{private:



public:
void Driver();
void EncFileUsingRot(int rotNum);
void EncFileUsingCrypto(string file);
void DecFileUsingRot(int rotNum);
void DecFileUsingCrypto(string file);
};
```

Security.cpp

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include "Security.h"

using namespace std;
```

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: Without minimal example code that reproduces the issue, we cannot help you: there are so many things that could go wrong which your textual description cannot possibly convey.

Comment: 'I know I'm not supposed to "include" anything in these files'. Why? The error does sounds like you should be including something you are not. But if you really want some help you are going to have to post the code. Isn't that obvious?

Comment: Original post edited with section of code.

Comment: I'm sorry sir, but I'm a little confused: what is so difficult in understanding the error? It is explicitly saying that the type `string` is not declared in the scope. The first thing to look at, in this kind of problems, is the header files included (and you have none). Are we sure you have a minimal understanding of the problem being solved?

Answer (score 2):

Two errors.

Firstly Security.h should have

```
#include <string>
```

Secondly

```
void EncFileUsingCrypto(string file);
```

should be

```
void EncFileUsingCrypto(std::string file);
```

and

```
void DecFileUsingCrypto(string file);
```

should be

```
void DecFileUsingCrypto(std::string file);
```

Comment: I'm a newb, but why would I have to do that with string but not int?

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII, `string` is not a primitive type, `int` is instead.

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII Because `int` is a builtin type, while `std::string` is part of the `std` namespace (and is part of the standard library, defined in the `<string>` header).

Comment: It's because int is built in to the language, you don't need to do anything to use it. But string is part of the the standard library, so it needs the correct header file (and say std::).

Comment: Well I guess that clears that up for me.  I was under the impression that string was a primitive type.

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII, if you had that impression I seriously suggest you to read a good book on C++ before going further.

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII: Don't confuse C-style "strings" with the type `string`. The former is not a type; it's just a sequence of characters up to and including the terminating null character `'\0'`. `string`, more properly `std::string`, is a non-primitive type (a class) defined in the `<string>` header.